# How to add new text field when button is clicked then collect the value of each added text field?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

I can already add new text field on the click of the button, however I need to collect the value of each added text field and save those into the database (mysql)

[This is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofGBl.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array to push each new word/ modified word into with something like this:

```
const words= [];
words.push("WORD");
```

See more at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Now, regarding the MySQL part : you can not achieve access to a database from pure JavaScript on client side. You would need NodeJS in order to achieve access.